# Docker build error on django application with numpy

Tags: python, django, docker, pip

I am trying to docker build my django application but i am getting this error when it install the requirements.txt:

```
 Running from numpy source directory.
#7 83.21             setup.py:480: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
#7 83.21               run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
```

This is my requirement.txt:

```
    -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
    Django==4.0.6
    fastbook==0.0.26
    gunicorn==20.1.0
    Pillow==9.2.0
    torch==1.12.0+cpu
    torchvision==0.13.0+cpu
```

And this is my dockerfile:

```
    #Python and Linux Version
    FROM python:3.9-alpine3.15
    
    COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
    
    #Configure server
    RUN set -ex \
        && pip install --upgrade pip \
        && pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt
    
    #Working directory
    
    WORKDIR /app
    
    ADD . .
    
    EXPOSE 8000
    
    CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", ":8000","--workers", "3", "hongOS_project.wsgi:application"]
```

Comment: Are you fixed on using alpine?

Comment: to be honest i don't really know so i'll sey that i am not, but i suppose i am fixed to linux (?)

Answer (score 0):

Okay! apparently I solved the packages problem by changing the python image to use from `python:3.9-alpine3.15` to `python:3.9-alpine3.15` and by pip freezing all the packages installed on my local machine

Comment: Please clarify, both image names are the same, are they not?